# How to include an external file in DomPdf loaded file to render

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

the log.php page that i pass in input to transform into pdf is like this:

```
   <p>title</p>
   <?php include 'log.html'?>
```

I'm using this code :

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$file = "log.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html_file($file);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

the pdf result show only "title"

how can i add an external file to log.php and then print all in the pdf ?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the  `log.php` script is not server-side interpreted before you pass it to dompdf: it's simply loaded as a 'common' file

If you use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and pass to it the URL of the file, the file will be interpreted and its content will return as a string you'll pass to Dompdf:

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

//this will be something like: http://www.yourapp.com/templates/log.php
$fileUrl = YOUR_APP_URL . "log.php";

//get file content after the script is server-side interpreted
$fileContent = file_get_contents( $fileUrl ) ;

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

//load stored html string
$dompdf->load_html($fileContent);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Comment: This could work, but a better suggestion would be to use output buffering and render your PHP before passing it to dompdf, e.g. `ob_start(); require 'log.php'; $html = ob_get_clean(); ob_end_clean();`. Related: my comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34355543/264628).

Comment: @BrianS : i know you are the author of dompdf, so i'll take advantage of it :D : what is the disadvantage of using `file_get_content` in respect to what you have proposed? I use the `fgc` method all the way because i prefer to avoid output buffering while i can

Comment: it really depends on your use of dompdf. In versions of dompdf prior to 0.6.1 (more on that to follow) you *can* have dompdf parse PHP in your document. The problem is that this exposes you to potential system exploit. If `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` is true the input in those versions is first `eval()`ed with the output captured by output buffering. If you allow user-defined input and do not rigorously filter the user content (and sometimes even if you do) then a malicious user could run arbitrary PHP on your system.

Comment: So if you allow no user input then you might consider enabling the PHP parsing. But if you're trying to avoid output buffering then you gain nothing because dompdf is using it.

Comment: You also have to consider which version of dompdf you are using. In 0.6.1 we removed the PHP pre-processing step. So in any new releases you can't have dompdf parse your PHP anyway. We're slowly moving away from parsing PHP entirely so that we can avoid potential system exploit using the library. But we're not there yet so embedded script is still supported (for now).

Comment: Also I just want to note that I'm just a maintainer, definitely not the author ;)

Comment: @BrianS :  ok...i thought you were the author :) The thing i don't undestand is: with `file_get_contents` dompdf is not going to do any php pre-processing...is it right? It's the `fgc` call that will make the pre-processing and get an html string that will be passed to dompdf

Comment: `file_get_contents()` does not parse any PHP in a file. That function just returns the contents of a file as-is. Unless the file is grabbed through a web server (e.g. `file_get_contents('http://example.com/html.php)`) in which case you would get the parsed file. If you want to parse a local file you either have to `require` or `include` it, or `eval` it (which most anyone would recommend against).

Comment: @BrianS : you're right. It was just that i didn't remember that to let `fgc` interpret the script, it should be called passing a URL instead of a file path. I've checked an old project of mine and it was called in this manner. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable  DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP in your config.

Comment: Don't do that unless you know what you're doing, though. It can expose you to system exploit depending on how you're using dompdf. Also, starting with 0.6.1 dompdf no longer pre-parses PHP code (e.g. `<% ... %>`) before rendering the HTML. Embedded script is still supported (e.g. `<script type="text/php">...</script>`) but only gives you access to the canvas object, it does not allow you to write out HTML for rendering.